# How can I do a "post :create" in RSpec when my route is nested?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

1) How can I use "post :create" when my route is nested.

For example... this works great as an rspec controller post :create with a top level resource, such as post

```
        it "should get a success response on post create" do
            post :create, params
            response.should be_success
        end
```

however, for a nested resource like 'comment' which is nested under post... the above would throw the following...

```
Failure/Error: post :create, params
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches
```

and if I tried

```
            it "should get a success response on post create" do
            post :create, post_id: @post.id, params #@post is defined and created above
            response.should be_success
        end
```

I get this odd error...

```
syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting => (SyntaxError)
```

2) Also, right now this code below is just testing a successful response. However, since I've gone and created a Post via FactoryGirl... how can I test the @post.id equals one of the id's being returned by the get: index json?

```
describe Api::V1::PostsController do

context 'Post' do
    before(:each) do
        @post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
    end


    context '#index' do
        it "should have a successful response on get index" do
            get :index, format: :json
            response.should be_success          
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a hash without the braces ({}) it has to be the last argument to the method. Your syntax error is because you start doing that but then pass a "normal" argument afterwards. You would instead need to do something like

```
post :create, params.merge(post_id: @post.id)
```

In terms of testing the response, the data generated is stored in `response.body`. You could load that json and verify its format in anyway you wanted